# Entangling two non-physically adjacent qubits

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, entanglement

Entanglement can be performed just between two ** adjacent qubits** (e.g. 1 and 2) or even **non-physically adjacent qubits** on the processor architecture can be entangled (e.g. 2 and 6).

[image: double T-shape coupling map]

How entangled between non-physically adjacent qubits could happen?

Comment: You are using incorrect terminology. Qubits 2 and 6 are connected but not adjacent. Since they are connected you can entangle them by series of swap operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@MonteNero](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/15947/montenero) mentioned in [the comment](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29328/entengling-two-non-physically-connected-qubits#comment38964_29328), it is posible to entangle non-adjacent qubits using [$\mathrm{SWAP}$ gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Swap_gate).

In [Qiskit](https://www.qiskit.org), there is a transpilation stage called *routing* that introduce the $\mathrm{SWAP}$ gates for exactly that propose. Taking the example from your question:

The following circuit entangles the qubits $q_2$ and $q_6$:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

circuit = QuantumCircuit(7)
circuit.cx(2,6)
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image: cnot between q2 and q6]
The backend you are suggesting has the shape many of the IBM's Falcon r5.11H, such as `ibm_oslo`

```
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeOslo
from qiskit.visualization import plot_gate_map

backend = FakeOslo()
plot_gate_map(backend)
```

[image: oslo coupling map]

The transpiler will insert the $\mathrm{SWAP}# gates to make possible the entanglement between adjacent qubits.

```
from qiskit import transpile

transpile(circuit, coupling_map=backend.coupling_map, layout_method='trivial').draw('mpl', with_layout=False)
```

[image: transpiled circuit with swap gates]

Let's analyse this case layer by layer:

- Layer 1, $q_1$ swaps with $q_2$ and $q_5$ with $q_6$. Logically speaking, you can see the connectivity map like this now:

[image: coupling map after layer 1]

- Layer 2, $q_3$ swaps with $q_2$:

[image: coupling map after layer 2]

Now, $q_6$ and $q_2$ are adjacent and the $\mathrm{CNOT}$ gate between them works.